# React prop type validation compiles the code without validation unlike React.PropType, is it a normal behaviour?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am using react 17.0.1

Here when I am using the package `prop-types` the validation does not work, however it works well with `React.PropTypes`

```
function Tweet({ tweet }) {
  return (
    <div className="tweet">
        <LikeButton count={tweet.likes} />
    </div>
  )
}


let testTweet = {
  message: "Some message for my first tweet",
  author: {
    handle: "@myname"
  },
  likes: "3s",
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Tweet tweet={testTweet} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This fails:

**npm i prop-types**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
function LikeButton({count}){
  return (
    <span className="likebutton">
      <i className="fa fa-heart like-button"></i>
      {count > 0 && <span className="like-count" > {count} </span>}
    </span>
  )
} 
LikeButton.propTypes  = {
  count : PropTypes.number
}
```

This works:

```
   function LikeButton({count}){
      return (
        <span className="likebutton">
          <i className="fa fa-heart like-button"></i>
          {count > 0 && <span className="like-count" > {count} </span>}
        </span>
      )
    } 
    LikeButton.propTypes  = {
      count : React.PropTypes.number
    }
```

Can we make it work like React.PropTypes ?

Edit:
**PropTypes are great debugging tool but a failed validation won't stop code from running.**

Comment: Use `import React ,{PropTypes} from 'react'` then!

Comment: `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` should definitely work. Do you have any odd setup that sets/overrides globals? Is this possibly a bug with React/PropType repos? React hasn't had `PropTypes` since back in React v15... are you sure of your React version?

Comment: I am using create-react-app my-app, and in package-json its 17.0.1 also on checing npm version of react its same. console.log(React.version); is also 17.0.1, and node version is 10.14.2

Comment: @DrewReese Its actually showing the error in console but its compiling properly unlike React.PropTypes which fails the compile if not validated prop is passed. Is this normal behaviour with prop-types package?

Comment: Nope, not that I've ever seen. Can you create a simple public git repo that reproduces this issue we could examine?

Comment: https://github.com/ajoshi31/react-prop-type/blob/main/src/index.js

Comment: Replace it with React.PorpType and compile, it fails and the prior case it compiles but console error message with it. As in many tutorial its written that way only. to see console error, if that is case I don't see the usage of prop type then.

Comment: Cloned that repo, ran `npm i` and `npm start` and the propTypes from `PropTypes` work as I would expect. Changed everything to `React.PropTypes.XX` and project fails to build, which I also expected.